# Getting rid of unnecessary lines (axes?) in Choroplethr

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

Whenever I make a choropleth using the Choroplethr package, these unnecessary lines appear. I believe they're axes, but the state_choropleth function shouldn't be printing axes.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(region = c("alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "district of columbia", "florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york", "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virginia", "washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"), value = runif(51))
state_choropleth(df)
```

This is the result:
[Map with extraneous lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2xmM.png)

Can anyone help me get rid of these? I've poked around in the Choroplethr source code but can't seem to identify what these are.

Edit: I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise, R 3.4.2 64-bit, and have installed choroplethr 3.6.1 and ggplot2 2.2.1.

Comment: Your graphic looks exactly like mine when I load cowplot. Have you loaded cowplot?

Answer (score 1):

Load ggplot `library(ggplot2)` and try `state_choropleth(df) + theme(panel.border = element_blank())`.

This removes the borders for the mainland US. However Alaska and Hawaii still have borders around them.

Comment: It's not working for me. All three borders are still there.

Comment: @JeffGrover I was missing a `)` at the end. Add that if needed. So its `state_choropleth(df) + theme(panel.border = element_blank())`

Comment: I included the missing `)` when I tried it. No dice.

Comment: @JeffGrover How about `state_choropleth(df) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = 'white', fill = NA))`?

Comment: Maybe a problem with your OS, R version or package versions. Are R and the packages up to date?

Comment: I've edited my post with that information. Everything is up to date.

Comment: Same issue here. My problem doesn't appear in the RStudio plot viewer. It only seems to pop up when I render it using tikz/pdf.

Comment: I've just debugged my issue. I was loading the R package cowplot. This reintroduced the axes when tikz created the images.